# Getting the power of exponent

Tags: javascript, numbers, exponent

Say I have a number: `1.25e-30`.

I would like to get the `-30` portion of this number.

How can I get it?

Comment: `Math.floor( Math.log10(1.25e-30))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `slice` with `lastIndexOf` - because if the base (`1.25`) is negative, just using `indexOf` will get that.

```js
const num = 1.25e-30;
const str = num.toString();

const res = str.slice(str.lastIndexOf("-"));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
(''+num.toExponential()).split('e')[1]
```

```js
exp = num => (''+num.toExponential()).split('e')[1]; 

console.log( exp(1.25e-30) );
console.log( exp(0.001) );
console.log( exp(1001) );
```